# Android: The AlertDialog is invisible when the Activity back to foreground

Tags: android

This question is related to [The AlertDialog is invisible when the Activity back to foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6303713/602011) post.

I have the same problem. The previous post is old, and have no answer. Any suggestions how to solve that problem ? Thanks...

Comment: Is your question related, or is it the exact same question?  If they aren't exactly the same you'll probably get a better response if you write out your question completely with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, Dialogs' states must be handled by the developer.

Simply keep a reference to the dialog showing

For example

```
Dialog showingDialog=null;
```

Now in onResume()

```
if(showingdialog!=null)
    //show the dialog and maybe resume some state
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to re-display the AlertDialog when in the activities onResume().  Using Google developers example you would be able to create an instance of this dialog and just recall it.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also we *all* create Dialogs on the fly whenever we need them, we should not.

Android way is (by the [book](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog)) to override an [onCreateDialog(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int%29) and [showDialog(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#showDialog%28int%29) in our activities so that our dialogs can be managed by the activity lifecycle.

Another way to do so is to use [`myDialog.setOwnerActivity(MyActivity.this)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOwnerActivity%28android.app.Activity%29) to tell the dialog it is managed by the activity.